# Load php file into div with ajax not work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tring to load PHP file with ajax without refreshing the all page and it is not work.
I have this code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#gohomw').click(function(){
   $("#center").load("home.php");
   return false;
});
</script>
</head>
```

and this is my div:

```
<a href="#" id="gohomw">go home</a>
<div id="center"></div>
```

when i click on "go home" nothing happens, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no element with the specified id at the time the script runs. Move the script so it appears after the element you are trying to bind the event handler to.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do action like that when the DOM is ready to use.

Place your JavaScript code in this snippet:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

You can have more informations here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Use below js code for ajax call

```
$('#gohomw').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "home.php",
             data: datas,
             cache: false,
             success: function(html){

             }
           });
});
```